# Slug - How to deal with Unicode or non-Ascii character

Tags: url, seo, slug, conventions, urlslug

So I am learning Slug convention, but so far they mostly deal with English character, like "Hello world" would be converted to "hello-world", but there are very little information on non-ascii character.

I saw that some "look like" latin word could be converted to latin word, like `ă` `ă` `ą` `ä` would be convert to `a`, but for something like `こんにちは`, how should i deal with it?

Some website, like wikipedia for japanese just keep the japanese text as it is in the URL; some instead transliterate them, like `/konichiwa` and it tend to be all over the place

On top of that, there are symbol, like `¿` `¡` `、`(japanese comma) `。` (japanese period)

So what is the convention here, should these character be kept as is, transliterate, or be avoided altogether? Should it be all lowercase? Should we keep the symbol? If not how do we seperate symbols from non-latin word like Chinese or Abrabic text?